# Value after cryptopp base64 encoding/decoding not the same

Tags: c++, base64, crypto++

I'm playing with cryptopp and have trouble with Base64 encoding/decoding.

In the following code hypothetically `sig` value should be equal `tsig`, but they are different on a last character (`sig` bigger then `tsig` by one symbol). I've tried also change `insertLineBreaks` parameter in `Base64Encoder` but the result is same. 
    ...

```
RSASSA_PKCS1v15_SHA_Signer privkey(privateKey);
SecByteBlock sbbSignature(privkey.SignatureLength());
privkey.SignMessage(rng, (byte const*) strContents.data(),
    strContents.size(),sbbSignature);

Base64Encoder b(new StringSink(signedData));
b.Put(sbbSignature.begin(), sbbSignature.size());

string sig;
StringSink sinksig(sig);
sinksig.Put(sbbSignature.begin(), sbbSignature.size());

string tsig;
StringSource ss(signedData, true, 
    new Base64Decoder(
        new StringSink(tsig)
    )
);
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b.Put(sbbSignature.begin(), sbbSignature.size());
```

Try:

```
b.Put(sbbSignature.begin(), sbbSignature.size());
b.MessgeEnd();
```

---

This does not quite look right:

```
SecByteBlock sbbSignature(privkey.SignatureLength());
privkey.SignMessage(rng, (byte const*) strContents.data(),
    strContents.size(),sbbSignature);
```

Try:

```
size_t maxLength = privkey.MaxSignatureLength();
SecByteBlock sbbSignature(maxLength);

size_t signatureLength = privkey.SignMessage(rng,
    (byte const*) strContents.data(), strContents.size(),
    sbbSignature);

if(maxLength != signatureLength)
    sbbSignature.resize(signatureLength);
```

---

There's an example on the Crypto++ wiki at [RSA Signature Scheme with Appendix](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Signature_Schemes#RSA_Signature_Scheme_with_Appendix), but I think its wrong after looking at it.

Comment: The Crypto++ wiki pages on [RSA Signature Schemes](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Signature_Schemes) are now fixed.

Comment: Yes, it's working fine. b.MessageEnd(); - one thing which I missed.

Comment: Yeah, its easy to miss. `Base64Encoder` and `Base64Decoder` buffer data looking for the next complete block of 3 or 4 characters for encoding or decoding. Its also a problem with `HexEncoders` and `Base32Encoders`, especially when couple with a `FileSink`. `FileSinks` will buffer on 1024 bytes.